# Arduino Uno - XBee communication

Tags: arduino, communication, wifi, xbee, wifi-direct

I have two Arduino UNO, two Xbee shield, and two Twi Xbee (type XB24).

I am very new to xBee and my question is: Can I communicate each other via Wi-Fi ?

[image: Software image]

[image: Arduino and shields]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by Wi-Fi? The protocols are very different or did you just mean how to wirelessly communicate between the two XBee devices?

Comment: yea... wirelessly communicate between two XBee in Arduino

Comment: I've never used one with an Arduino but by default I believe most XBee modules are set for a transparent mode at 9600bps and will broadcast to all other modules in range so you can just send over the serial port at that speed and the other will receive it. But someone should be able to give an example of how to do that if you're not all that familiar with serial comms.

Comment: AFAIK you have to configure one XBee device as master/concentrator. The master then has to initiate the connection to other modules.

Comment: I see the Arduino-hater-downvoters are busy. You may want to post this into the Arduino beta SE where beginner questions are welcomed http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The image is of a Series 1 XBee. "Out of the box" the pairs are usually configured to talk to each other. They will also talk to every other similar XBee in range, but it is not relevant here.

The simplest answer is that whatever data goes into the XBee on one side, will appear at the other XBee and vice versa. TX/RX of each XBee will talk to the plugged in Arduino - I'm not familiar with the shield (excuse me, daughterboard) pictured but it will be a pair of digital I/O pins. Any digital data from the first Arduino can then be "read" by the second Arduino and the other way as well.

Note the shield (daughterboard) will have a slider switch. In "program" mode it echoes commands to your PC via USB (the X-CTU programming mode pictured). In the other position, it talks to the Arduino. A link to the shield (daughterboard) specs would help get a more specific answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. One more doubt .. with this XBee shield, UNO and XBee ( XB24 ) can I connect to my home's Wi-Fi network ?

Comment: XBee is not WiFi - they are different protocols. You would need a WiFi shield (oops, daughterboard for the purists) to talk to a WiFi router/device.